# glTexEnvf alternative for GL20 OpenGL20

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I was using function glTexEnvf to set one parameter GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS (with target as GL_TEXTURE_FILTER_CONTROL) on GL11, but on GL20, there is no such function exists. Can someone help with telling what function one should using instead of glTexEnvf in GL20, to change environment of texture. Also can i use different target then GL_TEXTURE_FILTER_CONTROL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just do everything in fragment shader yourself, in your particular case calls to sample texture has parameter LOD bias.